# how to return the lastest info using sql 

Tags: sql, mysql

i want to get the lastest  info in the databse using sql ,

this is my datbase's table

[image]

what can i do ,

i want to get the  last  **address_reality**

the table's name is 'location'

thanks

Comment: Latest info of what? You need to be a little bit more specific here...

Comment: "last" by what ordering criteria?? Is there a **date** field to go on? A consecutive **ID** of some sorts???

Answer (score 0):

You can use DESC in the SQL query to get the results in descending order from Database.

Then use this query if you are incrementing a primary key id.

```
String sql = "SELECT a.id,a.type,a.remark from  accounts_command_type  a WHERE a.response = '"
                + response + "' ORDER BY a.id DESC";
```

Comment: You can use TOP 1 in select query above to get the latest one record.

Comment: Please, please, pretty please, never ever suggest embedding values in SQL statements by string concatenation or formatting. What if the `response` contained an `'`?

Every database API supports placeholders and "binding" values, which properly takes care of quoting and is usually faster, especially when you can use the same statement multiple times with just different values.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add one more column to the table which is primary key and autoincremented locationid for example. Then you can use below query.

```
SELECT TOP 1 address_reality from location order by locationid DESC
```

Comment: if i wnat get 2 info, Do i change the 1 to 2 , like this : SELECT TOP 2 address_reality , yes ..

Comment: It will return 2 latest records. Hope thats what you are lookng for.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @zjm1126 Yes this can be used